# Drawable Serializable or not or sometimes?

Tags: android, serialization, drawable

I have a problem with the serialization.

I have a HomeHolder object that retain some data for my HomeFragment.
The HomeHolder is composed of 1 String, 2 ArrayList of HashMap of String, and 1 MediaHolder object that contains 2 String and 2 Drawable.

When i rotate my device, i want to restore data contained in my HomeHolder. So i try to implements the Serializable interface in my HomeHolder and my MediaHolder. I'm pretty sure that Drawable is not Serializable, but let's try...

I put my HomeHolder as a Serializable object in the Bundle of saveInstanceState method of the activity that hold my HomeFragment (yes i need to use this HomeHolder in other fragments that HomeFragment so i retain it in my activity) and restore it with onRestoreInstanceState

Well, now i will rotate my HomeFragment and surprise : it work's !! (Don't ask me why). The data are not load from web but restored from my HomeHolder held by the activity.
Now i click on a ImageView(for example) that launch a new activity. And oh re-surprise : the application crash... the Drawable objects in my Mediaholder seem to became not serializable.

So my question is : is Drawable Serializable, NotSerializable or SometimesSerializable ?

(I could give you some code but it is useless : that are just classic objects with getter/setter and a classic onSave/onRestore implementation).

EDIT : i saw with the debugger that my HomeHolder objects are exactly the same when i rotate or when i click on the imageview. Nothing is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *not* hold onto Drawables past the lifecycle of that of their owner Activities, see related [Google documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html):

> Caution: While you can return any object, you should never pass an
>   object that is tied to the Activity, such as a Drawable, an Adapter, a
>   View or any other object that's associated with a Context. If you do,
>   it will leak all the views and resources of the original activity
>   instance. (Leaking resources means that your application maintains a
>   hold on them and they cannot be garbage-collected, so lots of memory
>   can be lost.)

The correct way is to save only the screen state, and recreate the new screen using the screen state, and reloading the rest of the data. For your web-loaded data you can save them as raw data in memory or as Bitmaps caches. The big difference between a Bitmap and a Drawable is that Bitmap is not tied to any Context and is therefore usable anywhere.

For ways to improve screen rotation speed, check this Google Blog: [Faster screen orientation change](http://android-developers.blogspot.tw/2009/02/faster-screen-orientation-change.html)

Comment: Yes , i guess i should not... It was just a try and i will do with your way, but i don't understand why it's working on rotation and not when i leave the activity. Thx for the answer and the details :)